# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to do a quiz. I thought I could do a var and whenever the right answer is clicked it gets to 1 and when you then press the button the correct answer is displayed. The problem is that no matter what I do it doesn't work.

```js
var antwort = {
antwort = 0,
test: function() {
    if (antwort === 0) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "That's right!";
    } else {
        
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "That's wrong!";
    }
},

antwort: function() {
    antwort = 1
},
};
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q">a<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q">b<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q" onclick="antwort()">c<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q">d<br>
<button id="submit" onclick="test()">Show Results</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment, not a comparison ... take `==` or better `===` instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Comment: So I tried using == and === but it still doesn't work.
The Error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id" Anyone got an idea why?

Comment: Did you put it in the if statement?

Comment: yup I did but it still doesnt work

Comment: `antwort = 0` **is** a syntax error because it should be `antwort: 0`. Then all your usages of `antwort` in the functions should be `this.antwort` instead because you've also named your variable that has an object `antwort`. Which means that `antwort === 0` checks if the object is zero (it isn't), while `antwort = 1` will change the variable with the object to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

- to selecet a different name for flag and function,
- to use functions from the object,
- to take better a boolean value as flag (which makes the comparison easier) and
- to use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) for addressing properties from the same object.

Inside the function, you could take a [conditional (ternary) operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for assigning the right message.

```js
var antwort = {
        antwort: false,
        test: function () {
            document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = this.antwort
                ? "That's right!"
                : "That's wrong!";
        },
        richtigeAntwort: function () {
            this.antwort = true;
        }
    };
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q">a<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q">b<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q" onclick="antwort.richtigeAntwort()">c<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" class="q">d<br>
<button id="submit" onclick="antwort.test()">Show Results</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `===` or `==` for comparison. I mean `if (antwort === 0)` or `if (antwort == 0)`. Thank you.

Comment: sadly it still doesn't work. It says "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing : after property id"